# Complicated SQL query

Tags: sql

Does anyone have an idea about how to structure the following query:

Tables :

```
TBL_GAME                 id,      name
TBL_CATEGORY             id,      name
LU_GAME_TO_CATEGORY      gameid,  catid
LU_GAME_TO_EVENT         eventid, gameid
```

So, basically `Categories` have many games.

`Events` have many games.

I want to generate a report that shows the `Categories` listed by how many of its `Games` were used in `Events`. Ordered by the amount descending.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Well I have it working when I show it by game  :SELECT g.TXT_NAME as name, e.INT_GAME_ID as id ,SUM(e.INT_QUANTITY) as total FROM LU_GAME_TO_EVENT e, TBL_GAME g where g.INT_ID = e.INT_GAME_ID GROUP BY e.INT_GAME_ID ORDER BY total DESC

Comment: So I need something similar where all the games belonging to a category are added together and shown under the category heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.ID, SUM(D.INT_QUANTITY) AS YourSum
FROM TBL_CATEGORY A --Adapt your selected columns 
INNER JOIN LU_GAME_TO_CATEGORY B ON A.id = B.catid
INNER JOIN TBL_CATEGORY C ON B.gameid = C.id
INNER JOIN LU_GAME_TO_EVENT  D ON C.gameid = D.gameid
GROUP BY A.ID
ORDER BY YourSum DESC;
```

Here i don't adjust amount, because columns does not exist. 
You must add Amount column in target table

Comment: The Table LU_GAME_TO_EVENT has a column INT_QUANTITY. So I would like this added up for each category. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Any ideas on how to adjust this query to provide the totals for each category? Currently the above query is return a row for each game/order

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
       c.id                 as catId,
       c.name               as catName,
       g.id                 as gameId,
       g.name               as gameName,
       sum(ge.INT_QUANTITY) as totalQuantities
FROM
       TBL_CATEGORY         as c,
       TBL_GAME             as g,
       LU_GAME_TO_CATEGORY  as gc,
       LU_GAME_TO_EVENT     as ge
WHERE
       c.id = gc.catId     AND
       g.id = gc.gameId    AND
       g.id = ge.gameId
GROUP BY
       c.id,
       g.id
ORDER BY
       totalQuantities desc,
       c.name,
       g.name
```